# AEM 6.0: EditConfig listeners of nested components do not fire correctly when a cq:template is present

Tags: aem

**Summary**

Example setup: I have two very simple components, components A and B. Component A contains 3 instances of component B. Component A uses a _cq_template to set some default properties for it and its children when it is dragged onto a parsys.

Issue: When a user drags component A onto a parsys, I expect the cq:listeners in its _cq_editConfig to fire, and they do not. The listeners do fire for the last the instance of component B, but not all of them nor for component A. In addition to that, when I drag component A into a parsys, it does not allow me to edit it (there is no blue border around it when I place my mouse cursor over it). This is also the case for the B components, with the exception of the one who's editConfig listeners fired.

**How to reproduce**

In order to reproduce this issue, create two simple components as described (one of them must contain instances of the other, and they must use cq:template to set default values). Dragging your component into a parsys will demonstrate the issue as described above.

Comment: Are you speaking of classic or touch UI? And do both component have a dialog (correct definition depending on classic or touch)?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'm talking about new Touch UI - both components have a a dialog.xml (for displaying in classic UI) and also a _cq_dialog.xml (for displaying in Touch UI), which appears to work correctly. Each component only has a single editable property which is a simple text field.